# How to configure multiple http proxies in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, http-proxy, wso2-esb

How do I configure multiple http proxies within WSO2 ESB? I have the following scenario:

```
sender --> WSO2 ESB -+--> http-proxy-ext --> server-ext
                     |
                     +--> http-proxy-int --> server-int
                     |
                     +--> server-direct
```

We have different http proxies for external servers (Internet) and internal servers (corporate network). So dependend on my incoming message I have to reach different servers which are behind different http proxies.

I already know about configuring the TransportSender in axis2.xml like described in http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server

But this gives me only the option to have one global proxy. But I need two of them.

Any hints are apreciated.

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can found a sample for this under [1], or you can use a message mediator to send your message to different endpoints.

Hope this helps you.

[1]  http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Sample+151%3A+Custom+Sequences+and+Endpoints+with+Proxy+Services

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Sample+2%3A+CBR+with+the+Switch-Case+Mediator+Using+Message+Properties

Comment: Yes, I know that I can distribute calls to diffent endpoints. But all http based endpoints make use of the same transport and so they use the same http-proxy. I need different http-proxies for different http based endpoints.

Comment: @user3087341 
I think I did't get your requirement correctly. Can you please explain your requirement bit. Can't you have separate proxy services if you need different proxies for different endpoints.